# Twitter Card Validator error when in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-card

I'm having an issue validating my Twitter Card in development.
I have configured my router's public IP to point to my internal LAN IP/port `http://119.21.79.135:3000`

Given the meta tags are in place;

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@flickr" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Mountain sunset" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Explore Reza-Sina's photos on Flickr. Reza-Sina has uploaded 113 photos to Flickr." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7334/11858349453_e3f18e5881_z.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.flickr.com/photos/reza-sina/11858349453/" />
```

I've tested this with a production/staging link and the Twitter card validator works.

However, in development, Twitter card validator log returns this error:

`ERROR: Internal server error`

Whenever I run the validator against my public IP, nothing shows up in `log/development.log`

Has anyone experienced anyone similar?

Answer (score 2):

An update has been pushed for the validator to hopefully resolve most instances where "ERROR: Internal Server Error" would be returned.  Please give it a try and let me know whether or not you are still experiencing issues!

I tried your tags on my own domain just now and the card displays (except for the fact that the Flickr photo no longer exists).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the update! I actually found a way around it, check out https://ngrok.com/ used this to create my "fake" public domain name in order for me to test my localhost server on an actual public url :)