# Local twitter card validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-card

Is it possible for me to test twitter card validation from a local host? i.e. http://127.0.0.1:3000/

Cheers

Comment: down vote but no comment? lend a hand

Answer (score 5):

It's not, the twitter validator must be able to access the code, and it can't if its local.
There are some free, limited hosting services, you should check some out if you don't have a server to try your code on right now.

EDIT: I just came across this other question on twitter cards: [Twitter Card Validator error when in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177835/twitter-card-validator-error-when-in-development)

The OP's comment on the answer mentions him using https://ngrok.com/, this could be useful to you too

Comment: totally right, this should be marked as the solution